# How to seperate the string that has comma and numbers and order them in asc and desc order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

The string is the value that i have taken from the input.When the user is going to put the numbers which the seperates them with a comma.And when he push asc the form with the asc order will be seen and the same with the desc order.I CAN NOT USE THE SORT FUNCTION BUT TO MAKE THE ORDER FUNCTION MYSELF.
Below i am going to send the code of the HTML.

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Numbers</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        p {
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 70px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <nav class="navbar bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" style="margin-left: 70px;">Sort the numbers</span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Put the numbers you want to sort below</p>
    </div>

    <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="numb"
        placeholder="Type the numbers seperated by a comma">

    <div class="dropdown" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="show()">Ascending</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="show()">Desecending</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
<template id="form-template">
    <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList">
</template>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="page.js"></script>
</html>
```

I cant sort them.Below i am going to send the js code that i cant do it.I want help with this.

```
let temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];


function show(){
    let clon = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(clon);
}

function showNumber(){
    let number = document.getElementById("numb").value;
    console.log(number);
    let array = number.split(" ");
    console.log(array);
}
```

Comment: So you just want to split the input with commas, and sort them by asc or desc, right? `234, 123, 123, 123, ` Will the input look like this?

Comment: @DreamBold yes and the output would be 123, 123, 123, 234 or in other order.

Comment: I have added an answer, please have a look and let me know!

Answer (score 0):

So here's your solution:

```
array = number.split(/[ ,]+/);
array.sort(); // ["123", "126", "127", "234"]
array.reverse()  // ["234", "127", "126", "123"]
```

Or you can use `sort(function(a, b){return a-b})` for `asc`, `sort(function(a, b){return b-a})` for `desc` order.

Answer (score 0):

When you reference your input-element you'll get a string looking like this:

```
const stringOfNumbersFromOutput =  "1,2,4,3,7"
```

Now, what you can do is call `split()`, this is a method that belongs to the String global object. It takes an argument which is a string or a `RegEx`.
You supply what deliminator you want to split the string with.
Read more here: [w3schools page on `.split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

You have a comma seperated list supplied as a string

```
stringOfNumbersFromOutput.split(',') // returns ["1", "2", "4", "3", "7"]
```

You can use any deliminator you want

```
"1-2-4-3-7".split("-") // returns ["1", "2", "4", "3", "7"]
```

Now! you can sort that array with `sort()`, it works straight out of the box with strings, but not numbers.

To sort numbers, you need to supply the compare-function
read more here: [w3school's page on comparefunctions](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

You want to do this:

```
   function compareFunction(a, b) { 
     return a-b 
   }
   stringOfNumbersFromOutput.split(',').sort(compareFunction) // returns ["1", "2", "3", "4", "7"]

a-b // will give you ascending order
b-a // will give you descending order
```

If you want to turn it back into a string, you use the `.join()` method, which is very similar to `.split()` but it will join an array into a string. It also takes a delimiter

```
   function compareFunction(a, b) { 
     return a-b 
   }
   stringOfNumbersFromOutput.split(',').sort(compareFunction).join(", ") // returns "1, 2, 3, 4, 7"
```

The comparefunction is explained nicely in the link to the `.sort()` method [w3school's page on comparefunctions](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Comment: Thank you but i dont want it with the sort function.

Comment: If you don't want the sort function you should read up on sortingalgorithms:
[link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/#algo)